# Toggle button to put in header component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm new to the react world and learning. I'm creating my app template, but I can't solve this problem.
I'm creating a layout component and i'm inserting inside header, sidebar, footer, main.
What I can't do is insert the button that opens and closes the sidebar inside the header.
If the button I insert it in the layout component, everything works fine, but how do I insert the button inside the header? The toggle class active button to the sidebar and the body container div.
I have to insert the button in the Header component, how do I do it?

I posted the code here, can you help me please?

https://codesandbox.io/embed/nostalgic-wildflower-w81pmq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I've tried putting the button in the header component, but I can't get it to work.
If the button is inside the layout component, it works fine

LAYOUT

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const { isActive, SidebarCollapse } = Script();
  console.log({ isActive });

  return (
    <>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Sidebar handleToggle={isActive} />
        <div id="body" className={isActive ? "active" : null}>
          <SidebarCollapse />
          <Header />
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};
```

HEADER

```
const Header = (props) => {
     
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-white bg-white">
        {/* <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" className="btn btn-light" onClick={handleToggle}>
            <i className="bi bi-list"></i><span></span>
        </button> */}
        {/* how do i insert the open close button here ???? */}
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <span className="nav-link d-none d-lg-inline-block">
                <i className="bi bi-building"></i>
              </span>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item dropdown">
              <div className="nav-dropdown">
                <a
                  href="/#"
                  id="nav2"
                  className="nav-item nav-link dropdown-toggle text-secondary"
                  data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                >
                  <i className="bi bi-person-circle"></i>{" "}
                  <i className="bi bi-caret-down-fill"></i>
                </a>
                <div className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end nav-link-menu">
                  <ul className="nav-list">
                    <li>
                      <a href="/#" className="dropdown-item">
                        <i className="bi bi-credit-card-2-front"></i> Modifica
                        dati
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `isActive` state & updater function into `Layout` along with `handleToggle`, render the toggle button in `Header`, and pass `handleToggle` as a prop to `Header`.

Example:

Layout

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const [isActive, setActive] = React.useState("");

  function handleToggle() {
    setActive(!isActive);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Sidebar handleToggle={isActive} />
        <div id="body" className={isActive ? "active" : null}>
          <Header handleToggle={handleToggle} />
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};
```

Header

```
const Header = ({ handleToggle }) => {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-white bg-white">
      ...
      <button
        type="button"
        id="sidebarCollapse"
        className="btn btn-light"
        onClick={handleToggle}
      >
        Open/Close
        <span></span>
      </button>
      ...
    </nav>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit toggle-button-to-put-in-header-component]

Comment: Thank you. I'm learning. These simple things become difficult. Thanks again